# start-all.sh command not found

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have just installed **Cloudera** VM setup for hadoop. But when I open the command prompt and want to start all daemons for hadoop using command 'start-all.sh' , I get an error stating "bash : start-all.sh: command not found".
I have tried 'start-dfs.sh' too yet still gives the same error. When I use 'jps' command, I can see that none of the daemons have been started.

Comment: Why are you not using Cloudera Manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `start-all.sh` and `start-dfs.sh` scripts in `bin` or `sbin` folders. You can use the following command to find that. Go to hadoop installation folder and run this command.

```
find . -name 'start-all.sh' # Finds files having name similar to start-all.sh
```

Then you can specify the path to start all the daemons using `bash /path/to/start-all.sh`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the QuickStart VM then the right way to start the cluster (as @cricket_007 hinted) is by restarting it in the Cloudera Manager UI.  The `start-all.sh` scripts will not work since those only apply to the Hadoop servers (Name Node, Data Node, Resource Manager, Node Manager ...) but not all the services in the ecosystem (like Hive, Impala, Spark, Oozie, Hue ...).

You can refer to the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=NrdnkzAaSiQ) and the official documentation [Starting, Stopping, Refreshing, and Restarting a Cluster](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cm_mc_start_stop_cluster.html)